# Parse Mime Messages using Java

Tags: java, multipartform-data, mime, multipart

I am trying to parse a Mime message using java. I was able to extract all the parts of the payload. But when i try to extract the attachment `bodyPart1.getContentType();` returns `javax.mail.util.SharedByteArrayInputStream` . Not sure how to extract the attachment. Attachment is not base64 encoded its a raw attachment. I will have to convert the attachment to base64 later. Any help us much appriciated

Below is the java code:

```
        byte[] data1 = data.getBytes();

        MimeMultipart mp = new MimeMultipart(new ByteArrayDataSource(data1, MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA));


        int count = mp.getCount();

        //Extracting MIME one by one
        String finalXml = "<finalXML><data>" + mp.getPreamble() + "</data>";
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            BodyPart bodyPart = mp.getBodyPart(i);
            String contentType = bodyPart.getContentType();

            if (contentType.startsWith("text/xml")) {
                String temp = (String) bodyPart.getContent();
                temp = temp.replaceAll("<\\?xml.*?\\?>", "");
                temp = temp.replaceAll("<!DOCTYPE((.|\n|\r)*?)\">", "");
                finalXml += "<data>" + temp + "</data>";

            } else if (contentType.startsWith("multipart/")) {

                MimeMultipart mp2 = (MimeMultipart) bodyPart.getContent();

                for (int j = 0; j < mp2.getCount(); j++) {
                    BodyPart bodyPart1 = mp2.getBodyPart(j);
                    String contentType1 = bodyPart1.getContentType();
                    if (contentType1.startsWith("text/xml")) {
                        finalXml += "<data>" + bodyPart1.getContent() + "</data>";
                    } else if (contentType1.startsWith("application/pdf")) {
                        finalXml = finalXml + ("<attachment>" + bodyPart1.getContent() + "</attachment>");
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        finalXml += "</finalXML>";
```

Below is the input payload:

```
        ------=_Part_848_2117327112.1624968206416
    Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8

Content-ID: 1624968206416.94980599
  <Response>
        <Status code="200" text="OK"/>
        <DataResponse>
            
                <Attachment>
                    <URL>1624968206411.1011779764</URL>
                </Attachment>
            
                <Attachment>
                    <URL>1624968206412.1163945904</URL>
                </Attachment>
            
                <Attachment>
                    <URL>1624968206415.246543996</URL>
                </Attachment>
            
        </DataResponse>    
    </Response>
------=_Part_848_2117327112.1624968206416
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Content-ID: 1624968206411.1011779764

<xml1>
<data>data</data>
</xml1>

------=_Part_848_2117327112.1624968206416
Content-Type: multipart/related;    boundary="----=_Part_849_1064293581.1624968206419"; start="<1624968206419.1600999517>"; type="text/xml"
Content-ID: 1624968206412.1163945904

------=_Part_849_1064293581.1624968206419
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Content-ID: <1624968206419.1600999517>

<xml2>
<data>data</data>
</xml2>


------=_Part_849_1064293581.1624968206419
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-ID: <part1@PurchaseOrder.b1>
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="100HTTP.pdf"

*****PDF Attachment*****

------=_Part_849_1064293581.1624968206419--

------=_Part_848_2117327112.1624968206416
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Content-ID: 1624968206415.246543996

<xml3>
<data>data</data>
</xml3>

------=_Part_848_2117327112.1624968206416--
```

The final xml is as below:

```
<finalXML>
<data>null  ------=_Part_848_2117327112.1624968206416 Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8 Content-ID: 1624968206416.94980599<Response>
        <Status code="200" text="OK"/>
        <DataResponse>
            <Attachment>
                <URL>1624968206411.1011779764</URL>
            </Attachment>
            <Attachment>
                <URL>1624968206412.1163945904</URL>
            </Attachment>
            <Attachment>
                <URL>1624968206415.246543996</URL>
            </Attachment>
        </DataResponse>
    </Response>
</data>
<data>
    <xml1>
        <data>data</data>
    </xml1>
</data>
<data>
    <xml2>
        <data>data</data>
    </xml2>
</data>
<attachment>javax.mail.util.SharedByteArrayInputStream@27a5f880</attachment>
<data>
    <xml3>
        <data>data</data>
    </xml3>------=_Part_848_2117327112.1624968206416-</data>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is that really *all* the input? If it isn't, it won't parse and  you should post it all for the purposes of the question.

Comment: Added the sample payload

Comment: Are you sure that's valid Mime Mutipart?. Have a look at the source of an email you received with an attachment to see what it normally looks like. It doesn't validate at https://www.mimevalidator.net/index.html

Comment: Its not an email actually. Its a multipart form data received.

Comment: OK, I thought not actually but I didn't find a general Multipart checker

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" javax.mail.internet.ParseException: Missing start boundary
` is what happens when I run your code on your last posted xml.

Comment: otoh the xml contained in the multipart submission [here](https://microsoft.public.biztalk.general.narkive.com/uzYgcG3y/xml-over-http-using-multipart-form-data) does not make the parser fall over.